# Google calendar outlook sync with current email address

Tags: macos, outlook, google-calendar-api

In Google calendar, I can create an account with my current email address, by clicking on the link:

```
"I prefer to use my current email address".
```

How can I sync this calendar with Outlook in OSX? I am using Microsoft Outlook for Mac v 15.15.
I have already synced my account in outlook with my current email address and I want to use Google calendar with my existing email address.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Transfer-calendars-between-Outlook-2007-and-Google-Calendar-3A133146-A30F-45A2-8CF6-701E5962DF59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) cover what you're asking for?

Comment: Thanks for the link @Andy. That mentions only about importing and subscribing to Calendar. I want to edit the calendar in Outlook client and sync it with google calendar(which is created using my official email address). So that I can replace my existing default Outlook Calendar. 

My thoughts: Google must be creating an alternate email address which is mapped to my current email address. But I can't find an option to see it, so that I can sync that with Outlook client.

Comment: I think I am trying to do something, which is possible only using a 3rd party software.
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/178189
`and`
http://blogs.wsj.com/personal-technology/2014/07/15/syncing-microsoft-outlook-and-google-calendar-a-guide-to-the-nightmare/